# Why does rotating an object on its axes in a different order result in a different final rotation?

Tags: objects, transforms

As in the first GIF below, the result of rotating X first and Y rotating is different from rotating Y first and rotating X.

And like the second GIF, the result of rotating the Z of two objects first, then rotating X first, then rotating Y, and rotating Y first and rotating X are different.

Obviously, although the X, Y, and Z values ​​of the object are the same, what causes the rotation result to be different depending on the rotation order? Is there a workaround?

[image: text]

[image: text]

Comment: What causes the result to be different? The different order causes it. By changing the order, you put the object at a different orientation when beginning the next axis rotation in the current rotation order. So naturally the result would be different. Is there a workaround? Yes. It's called Quaternions.

Comment: Try it with thee coffee-mug on your desk. (Make sure it's empty, first) :D

Comment: So the problem you're talking about is that my method shown above is a way to cause gimbal lock? I have heard of the gimbal lock problem. So, when I rotate the object like the above method, I set it as a Quaternions. However, after heard your answer now i think that I didn't understand how to use the Quaternions correctly.

Comment: [Rotations are not commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Euler_rotations).  ie the order matters. (`A * B != B * A`)  It's not [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)  which is due to "locking of a gimbal"  at  90 degree rotations.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the top middle of your screen you will see its literally called local. Change that to global and you should be rotating on the global x and y axis and z axis.
In the second gif the objects origin is at the corner of it (were the 3d cursor is) Fix this by selecting the object and right clicking then setting the origin to the geometry and it should be fixed.